# How do I open PowerPoint files in the browser?

Tags: powerpoint, browser

I want to open and show PowerPoint files in web browsers? How do I do that?

Comment: @JeffH: [Don't tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the google docs viewer as found at:

http://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: unfortunately it does not support embedded video files. either does Office Powerpoint Online.

Comment: The original url is no longer available, however, "you can still use the Google Docs Viewer. Paste this URL in a new tab:  
  
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=  
  
and then paste the address of the document you want to view online."   
  
per https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2015/02/google-docs-viewer-page-no-longer.html

Answer (score 0):

if it's content you're serving, try setting the content type to application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.